# Typescript: create union instead intersection when merging optional with required type

Tags: typescript, intersection, unions, mapped-types

When optional and required property are merged via intersection, required wins

```
type A = { who: string }
type B = { who?: string }
// $ExpectType {who:string}
type R = A & B
```

This may lead to runtime errors, when for instance, dealing with default params pattern within a function

```
type Params = {
  who: string
  greeting: string
}

const defaults: Params = {
  greeting: 'Hello',
  who: 'Johny 5',
}

function greeting(params: Partial<Params>){
  // $ExpectType Params
  const merged = {...defaults, ...params}

  return `${merged.greeting.toUpperCase()} ${merged.who} !`
}

// @throws - TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
greeting({greeting:undefined, who: 'Chuck'})
```

**Question:**

as what I described is how TS compiler behaves, question is, how to create mapped type, that would resolve that intersection to union

so something like:

```
type SafeMerge<A,B>=....

// $ExpectType {greeting?: string | undefined, who?: string | undefined }
type Result = SafeMerge<Params, Partial<Params>>
```

Example with mixed types:

```
// $ExpectType {one?: number | undefined, two: string, three: boolean }
type Result = SafeMerge<{one: number, two:string}, {one?: number, three: boolean}>
```

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible, but hopefully I'm wrong. Starring your question -- curious case!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting a merged type that is an amalgamation of two types with each property a union of possibilities is simple. We can just use a mapped type, over the keys of both constituent types:

```
type SafeMerge<T, U> = {
  [P in keyof T |  keyof U] : 
    | (T extends Partial<Record<P, any>> ? T[P] : never)
    | (U extends Partial<Record<P, any>> ? U[P] : never)
}
type Result = SafeMerge<{one: number, two:string }, {one?: number, three: boolean }>
// Result: 
// type Result = {
//     one: number | undefined;
//     two: string;
//     three: boolean;
// }
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygQwGZQLJQE4HMoB4AqANDAKoB8MAvDAN7AwwDaACjAJYB2MA1lGAPZIY+GAB8GvAUJIBdGAC4Y9BmJgAKEVAAeIKBwAmAZxjMEGEGwQAbXACUoAY34Z9uZsQQcwZCgH5hLHKKHFAAbpgAlMoM4mokMNq6Bsam5pY29k4ubh5ePjD+JIEKMCHhGFEAvqCQsPaGAK5WIFTwyGiYOLg0-CHBDQC2AEaYxCAA7vzyhiAYnFiVxD0hvv3DozAgABYYUFCKQ-z8VlCelWTAAPSXMPVNIIpXN+DQt1CNza101yoMvfulQYjDCqBoGKBIThQfQAbiev02k0UMzmHCwcJ+v22uwBh2Opw4GJulSAA)

The problem with the solution above is that we loose the optionality of the keys (also the readonly-ness, which is probably less of a concern for this use case). Homomorphic mapped types keep modifiers, but unfortunately we can't use one here since we don't really fit in any of the patterns for homomorphic mapped types (`{ [P in keyof T] : T[P] }` or `{[P in K]: T[P] }` where K is a type parameter with `K extends keyof T`, see [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12563) and [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12826)).

We can extract the optional keys and use two mapped types, one for any optional keys (keys that are optional in at least one of the constituents) and one for the required keys:

```
type OptionalPropertyOf<T> = Exclude<{
  [K in keyof T]: T extends Record<K, T[K]>
    ? never
    : K
}[keyof T], undefined>

type SafeMerge<T, U> = {
  [P in OptionalPropertyOf<T> |  OptionalPropertyOf<U>]?: 
    | (T extends Partial<Record<P, any>> ? T[P] : never)
    | (U extends Partial<Record<P, any>> ? U[P] : never)
} & {
  [P in Exclude<keyof T | keyof U,  OptionalPropertyOf<T> |  OptionalPropertyOf<U>>]: 
    | (T extends Partial<Record<P, any>> ? T[P] : never)
    | (U extends Partial<Record<P, any>> ? U[P] : never)
}

type Result = SafeMerge<{one: number, two:string, three: number}, {one?: number, three: boolean}>
// Result: 
// type Result = {
//     one?: number | undefined;
// } & {
//     two: string;
//     three: number | boolean;
// }

type Id<T> = {} & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }
type FlattenedResult = Id<SafeMerge<{one: number, two:string, three: number }, {one?: number, three: boolean}>>
// type FlattenedResult = {
//     one?: number | undefined;
//     two: string;
//     three: number | boolean;
// }
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-6wPbkHdHmxd0fC501EA)

Optionally we can `Id` to flatten the intersection as I did in the example above, but that is optional.