# Typescript - Deep type Merge, including optional properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So far I have been using intersection (`&`) operator to merge two object types. There are certain cases in which intersection won't do:

- A property of type object exists in both object, and I'd like to merge them
- An optional property exists in both objects.
- An optional property of type object exists in both objects.

I'm looking for a generic that can handle those cases as well.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474241/typescript-create-union-instead-intersection-when-merging-optional-with-require) shows how it is possible to isolate optional properties.

Comment: I think you're just looking for union operator. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

Comment: @ritaj, I union operator is not a merge operator, but an `or` operator. the new type would have either the properties of one, or the properties of the other, but not of both.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly thank you for the link for similar issue, I took from there utility type - `OptionalPropertyOf`. Below the solution of your problem

```
type OptionalPropertyOf<T> = Exclude<{
  [K in keyof T]: T extends Record<K, T[K]>
    ? never
    : K
}[keyof T], undefined>

type Merge<T1, T2,
    First = {
        [K in (keyof T1)]: K extends keyof T2 ? T1[K] | T2[K] : T1[K]
    }, OptionalSecond = {
        [K in Exclude<OptionalPropertyOf<T2>, keyof T1>]+?: T2[K]
    },
    NonOptionalSecond = {
        [K in Exclude<keyof T2, keyof First | keyof OptionalSecond>]: T2[K]
    }> = First & OptionalSecond & NonOptionalSecond

// Example
type A = {
    a: string,
    b?: number,
    f: number,
}
type B = {
    a: boolean,
    b? : string,
    c?: string,
    e: number
}
type C = Merge<A, B>
/* type C evaluated as
{
    a: string | boolean;
    b?: string | number | undefined;
    f: number;
    c?: string | undefined;
    e: number;
}

*/
const value: C = {
    a: true,
    e: 1,
    f: 2
}
```

There are three steps we did:

- type `First` represents all fields of `T1` + if `T2` has the same field we merge it by union
- type `OptionalSecond` represents fields which are optional in `T2` but were not used in type `First`. We say here `+?` in order to say these fields remain optional here
- type `NonOptionalSecond` represents every field which is in `T2` which is additional and non-optional

In result we have all optional fields from both types, also in situation of duplication merge is done by union.

Comment: What if one is optional in one object, but required in the other?